# Fragment getView gives null after suspend

Tags: android, android-fragments

In order to focus on the problem I ended with the following test app which contains one activity and two fragments which are connected to FragmentStatePagerAdapter / ViewPager. I also have Runnable and Handler printing getView() every second (in production version it is used to show time in fragment's TextView).

When I start app, getView() shows maybe few nulls (I suppose due to fragment life cycle) and then I get some non nulls which is ok...

But if I suspend and wake up my device LogCat shows nulls all the time.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    private Fragment myFragment1 = new MyFragment1();
    private Fragment myFragment2 = new MyFragment2();

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        timer = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(myFragment1.getView()); // HERE getView gives null
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // refreshing every 1 sec
            }
        };

        handler.removeCallbacks(timer);
        handler.postDelayed(timer, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        handler.removeCallbacks(timer);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment;

            if (position == 0) {
                fragment = myFragment1;
            } else {
                fragment = myFragment2;
            }

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Fragment 1";
            case 1:
                return "Fragment 2";
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

My fragment

```
public class MyFragment1 extends SherlockFragment {

    private TextView textView2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Fragment 1");

        textView2 = (TextView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }

    public void updateTextView2(String text) {
        textView2.setText(text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my problem simply by adding:

```
if (myFragment1.getView() == null) {
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
}
```

I'm not happy about this solution but it works...